# How can I change month/day/year character object format into date in Corpus metadata?

Tags: r, metadata, tm, corpus, tagged-corpus

I am trying to change the metadata in a Corpus but I have the day column displayed as 7/25/2014 and I want to make sure the console is understanding it as a date

Comment: What do you mean by the console? R? You want to convert the data from string to date?

Comment: Yes indeed @Chelmy88 I've been trying this but it's not working out

`> data$File.Date[1]
[1] "11/25/2014"
> as.Date(data$File.Date[1])
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
> library(lubridate)
> data$File.Date <- mdy(data$File.Date)
> class(data$File.Date)
[1] "Date"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without extra package, you can use:

```
data$File.Date <- as.Date(strptime(data$File.Date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```